# Admin Dashboard - Recent Comments source

Tags: comments, admin, dashboard

I need to see the source file for the admin dashboard widget that shows recent comments, can anyone point me to the exact php file that does this? I can't find it anywhere on the codex or in google searches.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s located under [`wp-admin/includes/dashboard.php` on line 612](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6.1/wp-admin/includes/dashboard.php#L612) and the function which calls the widget is `wp_dashboard_recent_comments()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do in this situations:

#### 1) Inspect the element

[image]

#### 2) Do a global search within my local WP copy

[image]